# Angular JS 'Startswith' custom filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, filter, startswith

So I've been trying a while to make a custom filter that searches for the 'Startswith' parameters rather than the 'Contains'. Every filter that I've written haven't seem to work properly. Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve ---> http://jsfiddle.net/DMSChris/9ptr9/

```
function FilterCtrl() {
var scope = this;
scope.doFilter = function(elem) { 
    if(!scope.searchText) return true;
    return elem.last_name.toLowerCase().indexOf( scope.searchText.toLowerCase()) == 0; 
};
```

}

http://jsbin.com/OyubElO/1/edit - Here is where I'm at right now.

```
  <ul border="1px" ng-repeat="msg in messages | filter:search:strict">

<li>{{msg.last_name}}</li>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If `elem.last_name` can be a long string, you may want to consider truncating and then comparing with `===` to the text to find

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to add a new method to your scope.

```
$scope.startsWith = function (actual, expected) {
    var lowerStr = (actual + "").toLowerCase();
    return lowerStr.indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) === 0;
}
```

Then change the filter syntax on your element.

```
<ul border="1px" ng-repeat="msg in messages | filter:search:startsWith">
```

Here is a [working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bf0Kck?p=preview) with the example above.

Comment: @Robin I've added a plunkr with the example.  What didn't work for you?

Comment: @mark plunkr doesn't seem to be there. But this worked for me!!

Comment: @Shadow thanks for letting me know! I cleaned up my plunks and accidentally deleted that one.  It's recreated now.

Comment: @mark This working perfectly, i just can't understand what is expected variable needed for ?

Comment: Extended question on this which formats the filtered result. Any help is highly appreciated!   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728544/highlight-search-text-in-the-search-results-using-angularjs-filter

Comment: Thanks Mark, Super solution.

Comment: HI Mark, this filter taking time when the array contains around 5000 values. So can you please suggest some better way to overcome this? thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working perfectly inside ui-bootstrap type-head too.

Answer (score 3):

Filter in object

```
  $scope.fmyData = $filter('filter')($scope.AllMyData, $scope.filterOptions,function (actual, expected) {
                    return actual.toLowerCase().indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) == 0;
                });
```

Comment: Hi @user35.. , any working plunker, please ? it really needs me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now pure `javascript` itself has the `startsWith()` method on strings.  But it will not be supported by `IE11`.

See here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith