# Filter the list with letter in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list displayed in table where I need to filter the result with first letter of name,above the list I have a letter A B C D and so on.
After click the letter list will be filter by its first name

For ex: list details are `Apple Boy Bridge` 
after click `A`, `Apple` will be displayed

Comment: Hi Sikander i think this will answer your question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501300/angular-js-startswith-custom-filter

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of fruit, I had to filter names of countries to display their sales representatives:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('sodemo')
.filter('firstLetter', function () {
    return function (input, letter) {
        input = input || [];
        var out = [];
        input.forEach(function (item) {
            //console.log("current item is", item, item.charAt(0));
            if (item.charAt(0).toLowerCase() == letter) {
                out.push(item);
            }
        });
        return out;
    }
});
```

A quick way to generate an array with letters of the alphabet:

```
$scope.alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
```

and the view, which also sets a different background colour if the letter is active:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-alphabet btn btn-default" ng-repeat="letter in alphabet" ng-click="setActiveLetter(letter)" ng-class="{'btn-primary': letter==activeLetter}">{{letter}}</button>
```

I filtered elements of the array of countries like this:

```
<ul class="list-group countries-salesreps" >
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="country in filteredCountriesArray = (countriesArray | firstLetter:activeLetter)" ng-click="showSalesRep(country)" ng-class="{'btn-primary': country==currentCountry}">{{country}}</li>
 </ul>
```

You can check if there are elements in the filtered list using `.length`:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" ng-hide="filteredCountriesArray.length">No available countries starting with <em>{{activeLetter}}</em></div>
```

Comment: On ng-click you use a function called `setActiveLetter(letter)` but don't actually list the function.  Use this in your controller: `$scope.setActiveLetter = function(letter) { $scope.activeLetter = letter; };`  Hope that helps somebody who sees this.   Fantastic solution btw!

Answer (score 3):

So the question has been answered but I came across this looking for an answer and being quite new to angular found it kind of hard to read and understand properly. I then found this tutorial explaining filters and how they work in general and in his examples he creates a 'startsWithLetter' filter which I found quite useful: http://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/

Just thought I would post it in case anyone had trouble understanding like I did.

Answer (score 1):

this is old but maybe [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/rZp7GehcAB973TLdHdSu) can help, using angular's filter filter.

Define an expression like so:

```
// Filter Expression
this.filterActive = function(value){
    if (self.active) {
        return value.charAt(0).toLowerCase() === self.active;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then in html:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="country in ctrl.countries | filter:ctrl.filterActive" ng-bind="country"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="javascript:void(null)" ng-click="letterFilter = {firstName:  'A'}">A</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:void(null)" ng-click="letterFilter = {firstName: 'B'}">B</a></li>
 <li><a href="javascript:void(null)" ng-click="letterFilter = {firstName: 'C'}">C</a></li>
</ul>
 <ul>
<li ng-repeat="name in list | filter:letterFilter">
{{name.firstName}}
</li>
</ul>
```

try above code this is simple to implement:

Comment: Above solution do not filter for the first letter of the first name. But applicable only for letter available in whole word.