# Search feature doesn't work when entering in parts of the name using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a search functionality from my table as per the `Restaurant Name` using angular.js. Suppose there are many 'Restaurant Names' and if user is typing the first letter of any name its not filtering as per required after typing 2/3 letter its filtering properly.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:10px; width:300px;">
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Type Restaurant Name" name="q" type="text" ng-model="searchProduct.rest_name">
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable" >
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Sl. No</th>
<th>Restaurant Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="detailsstockid">
   <tr dir-paginate="cus in ($parent.labelResults=(listOfCustomerData  | filter:searchProduct.rest_name:startsWith | orderBy:'rest_name')) | itemsPerPage:5 track by $index" current-page="currentPage">
  <td>{{itemsPerPage *(currentPage-1)+$index+1}}</td>
   <td>{{cus.rest_name}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Controller side code is here:

```
$scope.startsWith = function (actual, expected) {
    //console.log('hello',actual);
    var lowerStr = (actual + "").toLowerCase();
    return lowerStr.indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) === 0;
  }
```

I have many restaurant name such as `Anjum,A&P Chinese Food Express,Bookers BBQ & Crab Shack,Butcher And The Baker, Cactus Club Stephen Avenue,Cactus Club - Macleod Trail`.

When user is typing only `a` inside the search box the names started with `a` should filter but its not happening like that. All data is showing after type 2/3 letter the filtration process is working. Here I need when user will type the first letter, the names related to that search letter will filter.

Comment: I think that what you are looking for is **typeahead**. There are a number of solutions around (the one I tested some time ago was from the **Bootstrap** library: https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead.

Comment: @FDavidov : i need to filter some data from table after type letter in search box.Here i am using Angular.js.I am not sure whether it will work or not.Do you have any demo code.?

Comment: Sorry but no demo code. It was quite some time ago. I recommend you google for **Bootstrap typeahead**. You will see plenty of demos and sample codes.

Comment: @TahTatsumoto : Can you share your code by typing here for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

give a `minimum length` to the input

i.e, `ng-minlength = 1`

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Type Restaurant Name" name="q" 
type="text" ng-model="searchProduct.rest_name" ng-minlength="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular's filter expression doesn't do a `starts with`. It does a `contains`. With the examples Restaurant names you provided, Typing an 'a' in the filter will not filter out any names. The easiest solution is to add a function in your controller:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.listOfCustomerData = [{
    rest_name: "Anjum"
  }, {
    rest_name: "A&P Chinese Food Express"
  }, {
    rest_name: "Bookers BBQ & Crab Shack"
  }, {
    rest_name: "Butcher And The Baker"
  }, {
    rest_name: "Cactus Club Stephen Avenue"
  }, {
    rest_name: "Cactus Club - Macleod Trail"
  }];
  
  $scope.startsWith = function (actual, expected) {
    var lowerStr = (actual + "").toLowerCase();
    return lowerStr.indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) === 0;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:10px; width:300px;">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Type Restaurant Name" name="q" type="text" ng-model="searchProduct.rest_name">
  </div>

  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Sl. No</th>
        <th>Restaurant Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="detailsstockid">
      <tr ng-repeat="cus in ($parent.labelResults=(listOfCustomerData  | filter:searchProduct.rest_name:startsWith | orderBy:'rest_name')) track by $index">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{cus.rest_name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

For functionality, I removed the directive in my code. You should be able to just add the `startsWith` function and add the filter.

Comment: Let me to implement this.

Comment: Your code is working properly.But i implemented the same code inside my file its not working as per expected.

Comment: When i checked console message `lowerStr.indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) === 0` ,in your code its always returning `false` when user is typing something but in my code its first printing `false` then `true` and its repeating at the time of user entering any letter.

Comment: Try it without the directive in your code. If it's running twice, something else is triggering it.

Comment: you mean i will run without `startsWith` or what ?

Comment: I got one hint.Actually in my code i am fetching data to `$scope.listOfCustomerData ` dynamically. what i did not comment my code for fetching data dynamically and assign the static value to `$scope.listOfCustomerData` then it worked. Is there any solution for this type conflict.

Answer (score -1):

The below link can help you out.
It seems same as the one you are trying to achieve.
[Angular filter match by character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809551/angular-filter-match-by-character)

In the above link, they say about applying custom filters to have single character ( first letter) flirtingin angularjs.

Since single letter flitering happens in angularjs but it filters
like for character "S"
it takes up "Sandwich" and "Breads" too, though "Breads" is not valid item.