# Angularjs UI Select StartsWith search

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angularjs app I'm using  UI select.This is my Html

```
<ui-select name="service" multiple ng-model="service.ServiceName" close-on-select="false" >
                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Services...">{{$item.ServiceName}}</ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="service in Services | filter: {ServiceName: $select.search} | filter:myFilter track by service.ServiceId">
                      {{service.ServiceName}}
                </ui-select-choices>
```

Select filter provides contains search but I want to filter elements on the basis of StartsWith.I have seen a couple of examples of startswith filter but I'm unable to incorporate them in UI Select.

Comment: please also post the code of your filter

Comment: And no one of startswith filters that you found isn't working? Did you try something like [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501300/angular-js-startswith-custom-filter) ?

Comment: @MAkCblMKo I have tried that and put a debug point in the startswith function but it never hits the debug point.

Comment: @kabaehr filter: {ServiceName: $select.search} this is the default ui select filter which I'm using for search and myFilter is for excluding the selected services frmo the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Single item :** [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/pRrCkhxDqfTX3hY2frvX?p=preview).

**JS**

```
vm.startsWith = function (actual, expected) {
    var lowerStr = (actual + "").toLowerCase();
    return lowerStr.indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) === 0;
  }
```

**Html**

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="country in ctrl.countries|filter:$select.search:ctrl.startsWith">
      <span ng-bind-html="country.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
      <small ng-bind-html="country.code | highlight: $select.search"></small>
    </ui-select-choices>
```

**Multiple Items :** [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/KygKdwzw5DOnTQ5kaUWH?p=preview)

**JS** is same as the above.

**Html**

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="ctrl.multipleDemo.colors" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="ctrl.disabled" close-on-select="false" style="width: 300px;" title="Choose a color">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="color in ctrl.availableColors | filter:$select.search : ctrl.startsWith">
      {{color}}
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

Comment: thanks Sapath but it did not work in my case.May be because I'm using mutiselect.

Comment: can you put the url of the angular module which you're using (mutiselect) ?

Comment: Sorry Sampath I could not understand you?

Comment: Which `Api` are you using for the above  `UI Select` ? B'cos lot of apis are there for the same purpose. What did you mean by  `mutiselect` ?

Comment: Then why my above example is not working for you ? I have used the same api for the above Plunker.

Comment: Sampath\ by mutiselect I mean I can select multiple options from the available list as you can see there is mutiple attribute in my html.

Comment: It is working for `Multiple items` also.Please see the Updated answer above.