# How to modify angularjs filter to show only the strings that starts with the search box string?

Tags: angularjs

I have a drop down box with a search box above it.

For example, if my drop down values are:

```
Apple
Banana
Pineapple
```

If I type `apple` in my search box, I expect the filter to show `only` `Apple`, but not both Apple and Pineapple. My code shows both Apple and Pineapple which I don't want.

Angular code:

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" ng-model="itemSelectFilter" class="form-control">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="list-group" id="itemSelectorList">
    <a ng-repeat="i in items | filter:{title:itemSelectFilter}" class="list-group-item">        
        {{i.title}}     
    </a>
</div>
```

Here 'title' is Fruits.title.

Comment: I think you are looking for something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501300/angular-js-startswith-custom-filter

Comment: I did the same thing, but it didn't work for me.