# Highlight search text in the search results using angularJS filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, replace, filter

I've an input box which is used to filter out the results among the overall results displayed. I've a filter 'startWith' for that.
Now, I need to highlight the search text among the search results displayed in 
angularJS.

For e.g., when I type 'o' in the search box, it should highlight 'O' of the Orange displayed.

Could you please help me achieve this?

Here's my code:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 $scope.myData = [{
  'name': 'Orange'
 }, {
  'name': 'Banana'
 }, {
  'name': 'Mango'
 }, {
  'name': 'Apple'
 }, {
  'name': 'Pineapple'
 }];
 $scope.startWith = function(actual, expected) {
  var lowerStr = (actual + "").toLowerCase();
  return lowerStr.indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) === 0;
 }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentDiv" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="search.name" class="searchText" id="search_txt" placeholder="Search Data" />
  <div id="childDiv">
    <p ng-repeat="obj in myData | filter:search:startWith" >{{obj.name}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run the output through a function to check against your search and add a class to the highlighted part.  Props are due to this [blog for the reg ex](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/12/highlight-search-result-angular-filter/) (I hate regex but they work well)
also [google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=highlight+search+text+angularjs)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 $scope.myData = [{
  'name': 'Orange'
 }, {
  'name': 'Banana'
 }, {
  'name': 'Mango'
 }, {
  'name': 'Apple'
 }, {
  'name': 'Pineapple'
 }];
 $scope.startWith = function(actual, expected) {
  var lowerStr = (actual + "").toLowerCase();
  return lowerStr.indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) === 0;
 }
 $scope.highlight = function(text, phrase) {
    if (phrase) { 
        text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'),
        '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')
     }
     return text;
 }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentDiv" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="search.name" class="searchText" id="search_txt" placeholder="Search Data" />
  <div id="childDiv">
    <p ng-repeat="obj in myData | filter:search:startWith" >{{highlight(obj.name)}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```